# android google maps detect double tap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to detect double tap on google maps when and add marker I set `setOnMapClickListener` and set a time when is tap but when I tap twice a setOnMapClickListener is called only one time

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of the `GestureDetector` interface.

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class GestureDoubleTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event)
    {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
GestureDoubleTap gestureDoubleTap = new GestureDoubleTap();
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(YourActivity.this, gestureDoubleTap);

yourContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```